# Multi Image Upload Process In The Background

Tags: php

**I would like to know whether it is possible** to use PHP & Javascript alone for uploading images WHILE you browse through other parts of the same website as the upload is happening.

Meaning that after you were to, for example, click on upload... instead of waiting for the upload to complete and finally getting redirected to a success page, is it possible that after clicking on upload, you could then move away to other pages on the same website as the images get uploaded?

I did some research and I bumped across a concept called **Thread**. But I'm not entirely sure if that's the solution or whether it is a practical function that works in PHP.

If, according to your knowledge, this is not possible at all... what would be your advice for me to handle this sort of a client requirement.

Or, if it's not possible without supplementary resources, what are those resources I should consider.

In case this might be helpful, I'm working on an Online Database for a Garage that stores Job Card information. This particular Multi Image upload system I am trying to achieve is for uploading relatively High Resolution photos of the vehicles before the garage works on them. The system is meant to replace a slower and feature constrained MS Access DB.

Thank you for taking your time to read this. I will appreciate your contribution to this question :)

Comment: The only way I see this happening is if your website is an AngularJS app so that you aren't actually leaving the page but can still "browse".

Comment: Once you navigate away from a page, any outstanding requests generated by that page are aborted. You could work around this by opening an upload popup, overlaying an iframe for navigating around the site while the upload continues in the background frame, or using AJAX page loading. The take-away is that the only way to make this happen is to get a persistent frame for the uploading to proceed while the user browses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work involved is not worth it in my opinion. If you want to get hacky, then an easier way might be to create a new window that automatically minimizes.

Though, I'd just make users open the pages in new tabs.

Comment: It's worth it for me because it's a learning process :) Opening new tabs makes sense in a normal situation but as I mentioned, its a Job Card Records System. Therefore, other than uploading images, there is some other text data that is being input. Now the reason I needed the images to upload in the background is because I wanted to allow the user to move onto the success page which shows all data that was just typed in (thereafter the user could print that data out... for his client). The images were not required to be part of the print out so it was best for it to upload in the background.